# Generate new config files from a template in Yii

Tags: php, yii, console

I have config template files:

- `build/template/config/main.php`,
- `build/template/config/params.php`.

This is the template for `protected/config` config files.

How to generate new config files from template files?

I tried clearing the cache, but this is not, what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CMap::mergeArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMap#mergeArray-detail) for combining two or more config files. In your protected/config/main.php:

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    require 'build/template/config/main.php'), 
    require 'build/template/config/params.php'), 
);
```